# jquery to call ASP.NET MVC Render.Action

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

in my javascript I'm trying to build a string that will be html and inside that string i also want to use MVC's `Html.Action` helper.  I want to append this to some `<div>` element.    Works fine if i take out the line `@Html.Action`.   Am i going about this right or is this done some other way?

```
function Conditionalpartialview(MyParamID) {
    var html =
        '<br />' +
        '<div id="SurveyQuestionConditionalLogic_' + MyParamID + '">' +
            '<span id="SurveyLogicIDsarr_' + MyParamID + '" >' + MyParamID + '</span>' +
         '@Html.Action("ControlerActionMethod", "Home", new { ID = MyParamID })' +
        '</div>'
    $("div").append(html);
}
```

Comment: Thanks plenty for reformatting it Stephen..

Comment: You cannot. `@Html.Action()` is razor code and its parsed on the server before its sent to the view.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here? If you want to update the DOM, then you need to use ajax to call the controller method and update the DOM in the success callback.

Comment: So there is no way to call @Html.Action() from javascript.  Or there's no way to do this dynamically?

Comment: Short answer - No.

Comment: Yes,  trying to update the DOM.    But the Html.Action is call is calling a method that renders a partial view,  and inside that partial view there is a lot of dynamic logic for building controls

Comment: Instead of using `Action` helper which rendered by server, you can use AJAX call to an action method which returning view/partial view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it with ajax call

```
function Conditionalpartialview(MyParamID) {

var result = '';
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    async: false,
    url: "/Home/ControlerActionMethod/",
    data: JSON.stringify({ID:MyParamID}),
    success: function (viewHTML) { 
        result=viewHTML;
    },
    error: function (errorData) { onError(errorData); }
});

    var html =
        '<br />' +
        '<div id="SurveyQuestionConditionalLogic_' + MyParamID + '">' +
                '<span id="SurveyLogicIDsarr_' + MyParamID + '" >' + MyParamID+ '</span>' 
         + result + '</div>'
        $("div").append(html);
    }
```

Comment: This is exactly the logic i was looking for..    Thanks a bunch Usman